# Update Host VMM Microsoft Server 2012 R2 Error : The RPC server is unavailable,

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, virtualhost, virtual-machines, system-center

I have 12 host in SCVMM. In the Host status communicate is " Needs Attention" and i go to right click mouse on a host and go to Update agent check credentials profile and system give me this error :

///
Error (410)
Agent installation failed on s8-vrt-hvsr-006.mgkrk.int.
The RPC server is unavailable

Recommended Action
Try the operation again. If the problem persists, install the agent locally and then add the managed computer.

///

Firewall is off. I don't know how to fix this problem .
Thanks for all.

Comment: Hi Megarobert, have you checked the time on the hosts? do they match?

Comment: do you have all the needed ports opened on your firewall?